# HTML circle button with border

Tags: html, css

I want to create this kind of button.

[image]

For that I tried to create button inside another button. But it not worked. Then I tried to create a button inside a circle div.Then I couldn't adjust the div and button properly. It looks like this,

[image]

Following is my code,

```html
<div class="buton-inside" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: #1E1C1C; height: 120px; width: 120px">
  <button class="button" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: #1eff5b; height: 100px; width: 100px; margin-left:0.5px; margin-right:0.5px; margin-top:0.5px; margin-bottom:0.5px"></button>
</div>
```

So how can I fix this. Please help me !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `:before` button insted use `div`
It makes multi border(change `color` as you want and add `opacity`)

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid #f00;
}
.button:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: -10px;
    left: -11px;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 87px;
    border: 56px solid #252523;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
  <button class="button" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: #1eff5b; height: 100px; width: 100px; margin-left:0.5px; margin-right:0.5px; margin-top:0.5px; margin-bottom:0.5px"></button>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4):

Try this easy way

**HTML**

```html
<a href="" class="click">Click</a>
```

**CSS**

```css
.click {
    background: #06F;
    color: #fff;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:3px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #06F;
}
```

Comment: This is so easy.. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a second element (not even a pseudo element), You can simply achieve this with a [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) and a [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow):

```css
button {
  display: block;
  padding: 50px 38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: #19361e;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #19361e;
  color: #4bd763;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<button>Start</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following styles to "button-inside" div

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
    <div class="buton-inside" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: #1E1C1C; height: 120px; width: 120px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
      <button class="button" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: #1eff5b; height: 100px; width: 100px;"></button>
    </div>
```

Try this. Those flex properties should put the child divs in the center of the parent. I removed the margin from your code since it might not be relevant anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="parent">
    <button>Start</button>
 </div>

.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
}
```

You can try this link [codepen.io][1]

```
  [1]: https://codepen.io/venumadhavdiv/pen/rvMOjN
```

Comment: Answers should not contain just links

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS,
made some changes in your code

```html
<div class="buton-inside" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: #1E1C1C; height: 120px; width: 120px;text-align:center">
  <button class="button" style="    border-radius: 50%;
background-color: #1eff5b;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;"></button>
</div>
```